# Why is my binary search algorithm so slow despite theoretically being O(log n) time?

Tags: c++, binary-search

I implemented a binary search, and in theory should run in O(log N) time, and this holds up when counting the number of times it is looped through. However, when it is run, it seems to be extremely slow.

```
int binary_search(int i, vector<int> list) {
   int min_ = 0;
   int max_ = list.size();
   while (max_ != min_+1) {
       if (list[(max_+min_)/2] > i) {
           max_ = (max_+min_)/2;
       } else if (list[(max_+min_)/2] <= i) {
           min_ = (max_+min_)/2;
       }
   }
   return min_;
}
```

Can anyone explain why my algorithm is so slow?

Comment: We do not know if the data is sorted.  Please post a [mcve] that calls your function.  The other issue is that this `(max_+min_)/2;` can overflow if `max_ + min_` exceeds the maximum for an `int`.

Comment: When you compile the code are you passing the appropriate optimization flags to the compiler?

Answer (score 7):

For starters, you're making **a copy** of the `vector<int> list` that is passed in. Change it to be pass by reference:

Instead of this:

```
int binary_search(int i, vector<int> list) {
```

This:

```
int binary_search(int i, const vector<int>& list) {
```